# Local HTML File security on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, security

I have several local html files that contain various rich text elements like highlighting, but also sensitive information. When I open the html file, it will open up in chrome automatically. My question is, will this expose the contents of the html file to the web? Or is it secure?

Finally, are there any other options you would suggest using instead of the html file format?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the HTML file aren't exposed to the web unless there are other programs or plug-ins on the computer passing the data along.

It's always possible a computer is compromised, just make sure you're keeping your anti-virus up to date.

It seems like HTML's a fine solution for what you want to achieve.